# Idiomatic Nested looping in racket/scheme

Tags: scheme, range, racket, nested-loops

Has anyone got any idea what the idiomatic method for nested looping on numbers within a range is in Racket/Scheme? In Python we have:

```
for i in range(numb1):
    for j in range(numb2):
```

What would be the equivalent in Racket/Scheme?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Racket it's as simple as this, using [Iterations and Comprehensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html):

```
(for* ([i (in-range numb1)]
       [j (in-range numb2)])
  <body of iteration>)
```

The above will only work in Racket. By comparison, the following snippets will work in any standard RxRS interpreter - for instance, using a pair of nested [`do`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=do#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._do%29%29):

```
(do ((i 0 (+ i 1))) ((= i numb1))
  (do ((j 0 (+ j 1))) ((= j numb2))
    <body of iteration>))
```

Yet another option: using explicit recursion and named [`let`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29):

```
(let loop1 ((i 0))
  (cond ((< i numb1)
         (let loop2 ((j 0))
           (cond ((< j numb2)
                  <body of iteration>
                  (loop2 (+ j 1)))))
         (loop1 (+ i 1)))))
```

Finally, you can always do something like the following, refer to [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.3) under the section "Nested Mappings" for details:

```
(define (range start stop)
  (let loop ((i (- stop 1))
             (acc '()))
    (if (< i start)
        acc
        (loop (- i 1) (cons i acc)))))

(for-each
 (lambda (i)
   (for-each
    (lambda (j)
      <body of iteration>)
    (range 0 numb2)))
 (range 0 numb1))
```

Comment: As a small P.S. to Óscar's excellent answer: In Racket it's preferable to be functional. So you'll likely find yourself using variations of `for` that return a value, such as `for/list`, `for/vector`, or whatever. These are built on `for/fold`, which is the most general "iterate and accumulate" form. Of course, when you need to do something just for effect (like I/O) then you'd probably use plain `for`; plus it's simplest to understand, so it's great Óscar used that as the example.

Comment: Could you add the functional code ? These loops look like what I would code with Java in an imperative way.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan actually the named `let` option _is_ the functional way to do it: it uses tail-recursion and no looping constructs, it's just syntactic sugar for function calls.